# How should my RPM deal with the fact that the nginx rpm needs config files modified to run?

Tags: nginx, rpm

I am writing a very basic RPM that does nothing more then drop off a simple GUI onto a system.  It require nginx, drop some code into it's html directory, and drops a conf file into it's conf.d directory.  Most of the time this will likely be run on a VM or fresh box with little else installed.

While testing my RPM I noticed that the nginx that it installs fails out of the box.  The problem is that it's default.conf directory uses IPV6 address instead of IPV4 and the machine does not have an IPV6 address set, I gaurentee none of the machines this code is installed on will ever have IPV6 set.

The fix is [very simple](https://techglimpse.com/nginx-error-address-family-solution/), but my question is about good protocol.  I'm guessing it would usually be considered wrong to have my RPM modifying the default.conf of the nginx file to fix the line causing the exception, but at the same time if I don't my RPM will not function out of the box without someone manually making a tweak to the configuration files.  How 'wrong' is it to overwrite the default files if I'm mostly confident that I'll be installed on machines that don't have iPV6 addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check if you can drop something in `conf.d` to override the bad settings.

*Otherwise...*

Your `%post` can modify it with something like `sed`. Then put a flag there indicating you did, so your `%postun` can try to clean up afterwards.